# Get Class and Probability in Tensorflow Object Detection API

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, object-detection

I have a problem with getting the class and the probability of a detected object in the Tensorflow Object Detection API. I would like to print these two values with every image.

This is the code:

```
for image_path in TEST_IMAGE_PATHS:
  image = Image.open(image_path)
  # the array based representation of the image will be used later in order to prepare the
  # result image with boxes and labels on it.
  image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image)
  # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
  image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
  # Actual detection.
  output_dict = run_inference_for_single_image(image_np, detection_graph)
  # Visualization of the results of a detection.
  vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
      image_np,
      output_dict['detection_boxes'],
      output_dict['detection_classes'],
      output_dict['detection_scores'],
      category_index,
      instance_masks=output_dict.get('detection_masks'),
      use_normalized_coordinates=True,
      line_thickness=2)
  plt.figure(figsize=IMAGE_SIZE)
  plt.imshow(image_np)
```

Comment: much more information, please

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
my_classes = detections['detection_classes'][0].numpy() + label_id_offset
my_scores = detections['detection_scores'][0].numpy()

min_score = 0.5
    
print ([{'class':category_index.get(value)['name'],'score':my_scores[index]} 
        for index,value in enumerate(my_classes) 
        if my_scores[index] > min_score
       ])
```

Sample output:

```
[{'class': 'person', 'score': 0.5088876}, {'class': 'person', 'score': 0.5079384}]
```

Answer (score -1):

the following code give the possibility to extract the class id and the scores for all the entities with a score higher than 50%.

```
#Create indexes list of element with a score > 0.5
indexes = [k for k,v in enumerate(output_dict['detection_scores']) if (v > 0.5)]

#Number of entities
num_entities = len(indexes)

#Extract the class id
class_id = itemgetter(*indexes)(output_dict['detection_classes'])
scores = itemgetter(*indexes)(output_dict['detection_scores'])

#Convert the class id in their name
class_names = []
if num_entities == 1:
  class_names.append(category_index[class_id]['name'])
  class_name = str(class_names)
else:
  for i in range(0, len(indexes)):
  class_names.append(category_index[class_id[i]]['name'])
```

The if is necessary if you detect only one element.

Then you can print `class_names[i]` and `str(scores[i])`